# PayPal IPN Keeps retrying

Tags: php, apache, paypal

My PayPal IPN file has no issues and I can easily load the URL of it too with no error.
But PayPal IPN status is always retrying.

What could be the possible issue?

I am using ipn url of the form: https://www.website.com/payment.php

I have the following htaccess code:-

```
       # compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

     <ifModule mod_security.c>
     SecFilterEngine Off
     SecFilterScanPOST Off
     </ifModule>

     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$

     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

     RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]



     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$

     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

     RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php\?v=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: https://www.website.com/payment.php gives me 404

Comment: I gave the example of url.

Answer (score 0):

Your listener must respond to every IPN message it gets, whether you take action on it or not. If you do not respond, PayPal assumes the IPN was not received and re-sends it. Further, PayPal continues to re-send the message periodically until your listener responds, although the interval between retries increases with each attempt. An IPN will be resent for up to four days, with a maximum of 15 retries.

Comment: Thanks, good info. I checked and find that the issue was error 524. Timeout issue. My script seems fine. And I use cloudflare. What could be the issue?

Comment: I am not familiar with this error. The only reference I can find is [HERE](http://www.wiki-errors.com/err.php?wiki=524)